# howto change a value of jlist element in jpane dialog

Tags: java, swing

I am adding dynamically values in a jlist from a jpane.
When I double-click on an element of the jlist, I would like to change the value of that element.

How to do this ?

```
String bigList[] = new String[2];
bigList[0] = "first value";
bigList[1] = "second value";

final JList list = new JList(bigList);

list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
            int index = list.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
            System.out.println("Double clicked on Item " + index);

            ??????? CHANGEVALUE(index,"MY NEW VALUE); ????????
        }
    }
});
JOptionPane jpane = new JOptionPane();
jpane.showMessageDialog(null, list, "MYTITLE", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `DefaultListModel` to implement this. DefaultListModel has method `setElementAt("value " ,index)`.using this method you can change value of double clicked item.

adding this line

```
d.setElementAt("MY NEW VALUE", index);
```

will give the result you expected.

```
DefaultListModel d = new DefaultListModel();
d.addElement("first value");
d.addElement("second value");

final JList list = new JList(d);

list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
            int index = list.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
            System.out.println("Double clicked on Item " + index);

            //??????? CHANGEVALUE(index,"MY NEW VALUE); ????????
            d.setElementAt("MY NEW VALUE", index);
        }
    }
});
JOptionPane jpane = new JOptionPane();
jpane.showMessageDialog(null, list, "MYTITLE", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: GREAT ! Thanks you very much. Exact that what I searched for.